# What's the keyboard shortcut for MS Word's AutoCorrect Options menu?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, autocorrect

I'm looking for the keyboard shortcut to open the AutoCorrect Options menu (I'm using that name since it's what the tooltip shows) that's added when it makes corrections.

When MS Word (I'm using version 2013) makes a change with the AutoCorrect feature, it adds a small underscore icon (is there an official name for it?) when I move the cursor near the corrected word.

For example if I start a sentence without a capital letter (i.e. I type "simply").

> [image: type "simply" into MS Word in lowercase]

Word will automatically correct that to "Simply" and when I move back to the place that was corrected a small line will show below the "Si" part.

> [image: "Simply" was capitalized and correction marker added]

With the mouse I can hover it and show a button

> [image: Button shows when moving cursor or mouse pointer near correction]

that when clicked will show a menu with actions I can take on that correction.

> [image: menu shows when clicking the button]

What I'm looking for is a way to open this menu without having to use the mouse. The next best thing would be to revert that change other than <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> since that will undo typing "do something with it" before undo'ing the auto-capitalization.

Comment: What version of Word are you on?

Comment: 2013 version I think. I'll double check tomorrow

Comment: Yes, MS Word 2013

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These context-dependent icons with menu were originally introduced as [Smart Tags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_tag_(Microsoft)), they were [programmable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268890(v=vs.100).aspx) and they came with keyboard shortcut 
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> for opening their menu.

Although the technology was deprecated, the core look and keyboard shortcut remained the same, although [official keyboard shortcuts list](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-Microsoft-Word-2016-for-Windows-95ef89dd-7142-4b50-afb2-f762f663ceb2) now quotes it as:

> Display a menu or message for an available action.               ALT+SHIFT+F10

Comment: Fantastic! As a note, even though the menu key is equivalent to Shift + F10 , pressing ALT+MENU does not bring this menu.

Comment: @frozenkoi – such a shortcut expectations can be sometimes made when adding Shift key, but typically they cannot. Counterexample: Ctrl+Del deletes the word to the right, Ctrl+Alt+Del does something very different.