# MS Word - Shortcut to cancel last autocorrect?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

Often times when I'm typing, Word will autocorrect a word that I don't want autocorrected, and I will continue typing, either because I am not paying attention to the screen, or because I want to finish writing down my thoughts. I then have to reach for the mouse, click the minuscule rectangle under the offending correction, and manually cancel the autocorrect. This continuous switching to the mouse quickly becomes tedious, and breaks my flow.

**Is there a way to assign a keyboard shortcut to cancel the last autocorrection Word has made?**

[Another question](https://superuser.com/questions/1087099/whats-the-keyboard-shortcut-for-ms-words-autocorrect-options-menu) addresses a similar issue, but the chosen answer, in cases such as the auto-capitalization of a word, is just as complicated as using the mouse, as it involves manually moving back the cursor to the corrected word, pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>,  manually selecting the correct option to cancel the autocorrect, and then moving the cursor back to where it was.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> will back out of most automatic corrections. E.G. If you type a single quote and Word changes it to a "curly" quote automatically, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> should revert it, and you can keep typing.

Comment: I was aware of this behaviour. However, Ctrl-Z is only useful if you catch the autocorrect right away. For example, if the autocorrect was a few words or sentences earlier, you have to undo everything you have typed until you reach the autocorrect, and then type it again.